# How can I move an object to target more accurate more close to the target and then make the object child of the target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private GameObject rig_f_middle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true)
        {
            Vector3 moveDir = (rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

The problems with this is that the transform that move never stop moving even when it's very close to the target and I want it to stop moving.

I also want to make that the transform will get as much close as possible to the target now it's very close to it but not on it.

And last I want to make that when the object reached the target and stopped moving make the object child of the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a check within the update to measure how far away your are from the destination transform, like this:

```
void Update ( )
{
    if ( IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true )
    {
        var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
        if ( v.magnitude < yourToleranceValue )
        {
            this.transform.parent = rig_f_middle.transform;
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }
        Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
        transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Now, I'd personally go the extra step of only checking against `sqrMagnitude`, not `magnitude` as the computation is lighter, especially in an update loop, but maybe that's an optimisation you don't need or care about. Either way, you'd just set your `yourToleranceValue` appropriately, as a public, serialisable field, or your chosing. Then when the two transforms are close enough, it parents this transform, and also turns off this component so no more checks are performed.

Comment: It's working. I have another sub question. Is there a better way maybe a workaround to change the object that move to be child of the target more smoother ? The problem is that the game start when the transform is a child of a object and then with this script when he finish move I'm changing the transform to be child of another object and this change looks like the transform jump from position to position not smooth transition being child of one object to another. Maybe you have any ideas  ?

Comment: I'd be setting up an originalTransform and a destinationTransform, then Lerp betweem the to positions of each transform. i.e. this.transform.position = Mathf.Lerp (originalTransform.position,  destinationTransform.position, lerpTime ). Then when lerpTime >= 1.0f you change the parent from one object to the next.

But this is really another question altogether and it might help to get a full answer.

Comment: Here is my new question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330521/how-can-i-use-mathf-lerp-to-change-smooth-position-of-an-object