# How can I use Mathf.Lerp to change smooth position of an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform destinationTransform
    public float speed;
    public float distanceToStop;
    public float lerpTime;
    public static bool naviChildOfHand = false;

    private GameObject rig_f_middle;
    private bool changeNaviChild = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (IKControl.startMovingNAVI == true)
        {
            var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
            if (v.magnitude < 0.001f)
            {
                //this.transform.parent = rig_f_middle.transform;
                //this.enabled = false;
                naviChildOfHand = true;
                changeNaviChild = true;
                return;
            }
            Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
            transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(changeNaviChild == true)
        {
            this.transform.position = Mathf.Lerp(this.transform.position,
                destinationTransform.position, lerpTime * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead just changing the object child to another parent with this line :

```
this.transform.parent = rig_f_middle.transform;
```

I have duplicated the object in two places this transform when the game start it's child of a parent and destinationTransform is another copy of the transform object and I want to use the Mathf Lerp to smooth switch from the transform to the destinationTransform.

Here is a screenshot :
I marked with red circle the destination name NAVI Destination it's the same object as the NAVI Original.
And I want to use Lerp to smooth change between the original to the destination so the slowly the original will become disable and the destination will become enabled somehow.

[image: Original and Destination]

The main goal is to make a smooth transition changing the NAVI as child from one parent to another parent.

Comment: Use a Coroutine instead! You should always lerp clean from a fix startpoint to a fix endpoint ... don't lerp starting from the current position

Comment: @derHugo You mean the whole lerp should include also the starting movement of the object to the target until he reached the target and then make the switch with the same lerp ? one lerp for all the task ?

Comment: @derHugo Can you show me an exmaple please ?

Comment: What I mean is 1.  you should probably use `Vector3.Lerp` and not `Mathf.Lerp` (which is only for a single `float`) 2. you shouldn't use `lerpTime * Time.deltaTime` as a factor but something that grows from `0` to `1` and then use a fix `startPosition` and `destinationPosition`. They you are currently using the lerp only makes sense in usecases where you want to stabelize a certain movement to reduce jittering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is have references to the origin transform, and the destination transform, then Lerp between those two positions. Once you've reached the destination, then parent this transform to the destination transform.

You can use the `Vector3.Lerp` to lerp between two vectors.

Like this (written but untested):

```
public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TransitionState
    {
        None,
        MovingTowards,
        Transferring
    }

    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public float speed;
    public float distanceToStop;
    public float lerpTime;
    public static bool naviChildOfHand = false;

    private GameObject rig_f_middle;
    private bool changeNaviChild = false;

    private Transform originTransform;
    private float timer;

    private TransitionState state = TransitionState.MovingTowards;

    void Start ( )
    {
        rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find ( "rig_f_middle.02.R" );
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        switch ( state )
        {
            case TransitionState.MovingTowards:
                var v = rig_f_middle.transform.position - transform.position;
                if ( v.magnitude < 0.001f )
                {
                    state = TransitionState.Transferring;
                    originTransform = rig_f_middle.transform;
                    timer = 0;
                    return;
                }
                Vector3 moveDir = v.normalized;
                transform.position += moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            break;

            case TransitionState.Transferring:
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp ( originTransform.position, destinationTransform.position, timer );
                if ( timer >= 1.0f )
                {
                    this.transform.parent = destinationTransform;
                    state = TransitionState.None;
                    this.enabled = false;
                    return;
                }
            break;

            default:
                this.enabled = false;
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

That should get you most, if not all, the way towards a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably wouldn't use `Mathf.Lerp` which is for interpolating `float` values but rather `Vector3.Lerp` which interpolates two `Vector3` values.
2. I wouldn't use `Update` for this and poll check some state but rather a Coroutine which is way easier to maintain and control. It is also more efficient than having a most of the time "useless" `Update` running that is only used in one single case.
3. When using Lerp there are mainly two use cases

   - Stabelizing e.g. a user Input in order to avoid jittering. That is the use case you used. Here you would every frame interpolate the current position against the next input destination position, getting slower while getting closer to the target
   - Move smooth from one position to another. This is the use case you actually want. Here you wouldn't use a "fixed" factor but rather one growing from `0` to `1` and use a fixed `startPosition` and `endPosition`.

So personally I would rather use something general like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParentTransition : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Avergae move speed in Unity units per second
    [SerializeField] float MoveSpeed = 1f;

    // flag for preventing concurrent routines
    private bool isMoving;

    private IEnumerator MoveToNewParentRoutine(Transform newParent, Action whenDone)
    {
        // prevent multiple concurrent routines
        if(isMoving) yield break;
        isMoving = true;

        // Get current parent and position
        var currentParent = transform.parent;
        var currentPosition = transform.position;

        // Get target position
        var targetPosition = newParent.position;

        // Get the current distance to the target in order to calculate
        // the duration of the animation
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, targetPosition);

        // get the duration of the transition depending on the distance and move speed
        var targetDuration = distance / speed;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        while(timePassed < targetDuration)
        {
            // This grows linear from 0 to 1 
            var factor = timePassed / targetDuration;
            // optionally add some ease-in and ease-out
            factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

            this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetPosition, factor);

            // increase by the time since last frame
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            // "Pause" the routine here, render this frame and 
            // continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // to be sure set the target hard
        transform.position = targetPosition;
        
        // Now transit to the new parent
        transform.parent = newParent;
        naviChildOfHand = true;

        // Give this routine free for a next transition (if needed)
        isMoving = false;

        // Action to execute when the routine is finished
        whenDone?.Invoke();
    }

    public void MoveToNewParent()
    {
        if (!isMoving)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveToNewParentRoutine(rig_f_middle));
        }
    }
}
```

Personally I would remove the `Update` completely and rather add a

And then rather call this method from somewhere else whenever needed like e.g.

```
parentTransitionReference.MoveToNewParent(someTransform);
```

Using this you could use the same component for any transition between parent objects in general.

Then in your specific use case you would probably attach it to your navi and use it like e.g.

```
public class MoveNavi : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SeriaizeField] ParentTransition parentTransition;
    public Transform destinationTransform
    public static bool naviChildOfHand = false;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject rig_f_middle;

    bool isAlreadyMoving;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(!rig_f_middle) rig_f_middle = GameObject.Find("rig_f_middle.02.R");

        if(!parentTransition)
        {
            if(!TryGetComponent<ParentTransition>(out parentTransition)
            {
                parentTransition = gameObject.AddComponent<ParentTransition>();
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isAlreadyMoving && IKControl.startMovingNAVI)
        {
            isAlreadyMoving = true;
            parentTransition.MoveToNewParent(rig_f_middle, () => 
            {
                parentTransition.MoveToNewParent(destinationTransform, () =>
                {
                    naviChildOfHand = true;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ParentTransition ? It's not exist.

Comment: @DanielLip the name of my first script ;)

Comment: In the first script   ParentTransition naviChildOfHand and rig_f_middle are not exist, they should be ?

Comment: And the first script the ParentTransition should be also attached to NAVI the object that move ?

Comment: @DanielLip if you look close both are only still existent in the `MoveNavi` script. You could of course merge the scripts together. I just wanted to provide a more general solution which could be reused for many use cases, not only this specific navi with this specific parent transforms